# How do I render the primary menu's markup?

Tags: theming, 8

I have `{{ page.primary_menu }}` in *page--front.html.twig* and I have the following in the .info.yml file of the theme.

```
regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  content: Content
  footer: Footer
```

The primary menu markup doesn't render. What am I missing? This is a new blank theme (not a sub-theme of anything). There is no *mytheme.theme* file.

In the template comments, under 'Regions' it states:

> page.primary_menu: Items for the primary menu region.

I noticed that the menus don't appear in the 'Classy' theme either.

Comment: `{{ page.primary_menu }}` will render whatever blocks you have placed within that region. Check `/admin/structure/block` and make sure you have something in that region. If you do have a 'Main navigation' block or similar, make sure it has menu links to display.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed `{{ page.primary_menu }}` was variable containing the menu markup that would get printed wherever I put it in the template. Didn't realise it had anything to do with blocks.